# Why do some states have such opposite patterns of mobility for science and non-science PhDs?

Tags: united-states, early-career

The NSF conducts a survey of PhD recipients in the US. Among other things, they look at [which states are attracting many new PhDs and which states PhDs are leaving](https://ncses.nsf.gov/pubs/nsf19301/report/patterns-of-interstate-mobility-what-are-the-employment-and-geographic-trends#report-net-inflows-and-outflows-by-state). They break this data into science & engineering doctorates:

[image]

And everyone else:

[image]

The broad pattern isn't all that surprising, there are major differences between US states and it makes sense that some provide a good environment for PhD level workers while others don't.

However, looking closely at the two maps, there are some odd differences:

- California attracts a lot of S&Es (on top of its own large output) but there's a net outflow of non-S&Es. Massachusetts and New Jersey have a similar pattern.
- Wyoming attracts a lot of non-S&Es (it's actually about 75% if you mouse over on the map) while S&Es are leaving. Colorado, North Carolina, Georgia, Alabama, Louisiana, Utah have a similar pattern.

I would have thought that with such a broad grouping as S&E vs not, the dominant effect would have to do with having a PhD at all as opposed the kind of PhD. Obviously there could be differences between these two categories, but I would have expected differences of degree rather such strong opposites as in states I list above.

What is special about these states? How do they manage to be so attractive to one group of PhD-level employee, while being so unattractive to the other? Is this a recent development, or an old historic trend? Is it to do with the economy of the state, or some kind of social reason? If social, is it to do with the universities in these areas, or the population of these states in general?

Comment: This is asking for some pretty broad socioeconomic factors. Consider New Mexico - Los Alamos, Sandia, White Sands, and AFRL all hire way more PhDs than can be produced locally. Yet, there are few opportunities for non-STEM PhDs, whether generated in-state or out-of-state. California has high-tech, but a high cost of living. And so on...

Comment: @JonCuster Actually, New Mexico has a net **in**flow of non-STEM PhDs.

Comment: @Trusly But the net inflow is **much** higher for STEM PhDs: 98.9% vs 3.6%... Some of those may well be significant others of STEM PhDs who found good opportunities in NM.

Comment: Some of the Midwestern states have hugely successful public land-grant universities compared to their populations, and attract students from all over. One thing these data don't show is where the students originally came from, it just shows discordance between where PhDs are earned and where they are employed.

Comment: Because the states are different...